# Django - how to follow some object (not user)

Tags: python, django

Problem with follow button in django.

I have a web-site with database of some events. Registered users should be able to follow this events. I mean there should be a button "Follow" on an event page. Users who clicked it should see this event on their home page. But i just cant understand how it should work...

There is event model:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=26)
    second_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=3, default='cin')
    date = models.DateField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='images/',
        default='images/default.png'
    )
```

And i have a view to output events on a page:

```
def home(request):
    all_events = Event.objects.all.order_by('date')
    return render(request, 'events/home.html', {'events': all_events})
```

in template -

```
{% block content %}
    <h1>{{ Event.name }}</h1>
    <pre>{{ Event.date }}</pre>
    <pre>{{ Event.description }}</pre>
{% endblock %}
```

I tried to use ManyToManyField like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31845109/how-to-follow-on-a-button-click-in-django) but i dont understand exactly how it should work - what code should be in views.py, models.py and in template (button). Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step.
I think, the relation should be [ManyToMany](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships) . Event can be followed by multiple Users, and a User follow multiple Events.

**model.py**

```
class Event(models.Model):
    ...
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)
    ...
```

**views.py** user follow an Event

```
def follow(request,event_id):
    user = request.user
    event = Event.objects.get(id=event_id)

    event.users.add(user)
    event.save()
```

**urls.py**

```
...
url(r'^event/(?P<event_id>\d+)/follow$', views.follow, name="event_follow"),
...
```

**template.html**

```
<a href="{% url 'event_follow' event.id %}">Follow</a>
```

or

```
<a href="/event/event_id/follow">Follow</a>
```